# my div backround image is not responsive for mobile devices?how to make it work for all mobile devices

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, responsive

This is my CSS class which is working for desktop

```
.banner-img{
background-position: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://d14a6hhmw70jfk.cloudfront.net/spartans11/images/matches_banner.png?v=1523084431);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: yo can use bootstrap to achieve this. Or use css media query

Comment: check out the little code snippet i posted. resize your browser or run it on mobile and desktop to see the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>

.banner-img{
    background-position: 100%;
    background-image: (http://d14a6hhmw70jfk.cloudfront.net/spartans11/images/matches_banner.png?v=1523084431);
    background-size: cover;

}
@media (max-width: 750px){
   .banner-img{
       background-size: contain;
   }

}



</style>
<body>

<h1>Background Image Resize on mobile</h1>
<p>Resize the browser and see the effect</p>

<div class="banner-img" style="padding: 400px; color: #fff; font-size: 45px">
<strong>testing background</strong>
</div>
</body>
```